# ImageMagick installation on Debian

Tags: linux, unix, imagemagick, debian

I am trying to install an ImageMagick library on Debian.
After downloading unpacking the package I run ./configure command (in the ImageMagick directory and under the root) and it fails with some errors (in the config.log):

```
conftest.c:14:28: error: ac_nonexistent.h: No such file or director
conftest.c:79: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'text'
conftest.c: In function 'main':
conftest.c:133: error: expected '=', ',', ';', 'asm' or '__attribute__' before 'newvar'
conftest.c:133: error: 'newvar' undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:133: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
conftest.c:133: error: for each function it appears in.)
```

What I am doing wrong?
Thank you

UPD: version 6.7.8-8

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Instead of downloading and configuring the package yourself you could try the following (in console):

```
aptitude update &&  aptitude install imagemagick
```

It's quite a time since I have used debian, but I think this should work.